# How to acces XAML source in c# project (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

This is probably newbie question, but I would like to know how to acces (view) the XAML code in Windows Application Project (C#) in Visual Studio. I mean just like the XML code, that you can see when you create Windows Phone Application.

Yeah I know, that this might seem stupid, but I tried to google it and there were no answers.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to edit the layout of Windows Application I make in c#, but not by adding buttons and stuff from toolbox, but by writing XAML code...

Comment: Wut? This makes no sense, how are you NOT able to view the XAML? You just double click the XAML file in the solution explorer.

Comment: What type of project are you working on? if you want to create your UI using XAML for a Windows application, then that would be a `WPF Application`.

Comment: There are little tabs at the bottom/side of the XAML editor that let you choose between source and design views. Sounds like you want to select the source tab. You can also choose the split options to see both design view and and source view simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tabs at the bottom of visual studio should be what you're looking for.

The tabs shown below:

[image]